How to understand contraction and no quotation in this idiom
Does

Mum's the word.

mean the same as

"Mum" is the word.

?
Can "is" contracted with "mum"? Does the contraction here look usual in English? Does the contraction look more like a possession modifier rather than "is"?
Can "mum" be used here without being quoted? Is it the subject of the idiomatic sentence? Can an adjective be the subject? Without quotation, does it look like that mum is used for its meaning as an adjective not as a word as a noun?
Is the idiom better understood without the contraction and with the quotation?

It's a fixed saying. You might expand it to 'mum is the word' but surrounding 'mum' with quotes is not usually done. Mum here is a Middle English word meaning 'silent'.

It may be OK to quote other adjectives in 'xxxx' is the word constructions.

When one stays mum (adjective), one stays silent.
To say that "mum is [i.e. mum's] the word" is to say   You should be silent (about this).
"Mum's the word" is what granny could say to the grandkids about a surprise for mom. It's a sweet and gentle instruction to zip your lips.
P.S. As Michael Harvey remarks in a comment, the phrase follows the pattern of "{adjective} is the word", where "the word" is understood to have the meaning that "watchword" has, a word expressing a credo or policy that is to be kept in mind and obeyed or followed; the phrase reminds us to  act in the manner dictated by {adjective}.

In many parts of the UK, 'Mum' is what people call their mother, which gave rise to the second world war slogan 'Be like Dad, keep Mum', meant to discourage loose talk about sensitive topics.

Does the idiom mean the same as
"'Mum' is the word."
? Is the contraction here usual in English? Mum is adjective, and can it be the subject, if not quoted?

Adjectives can be the subject, eg "Tall is good". That's not a quote.

The contraction is perfectly usual.

@Tim - To emphasise a trend, theme or governing principle, we often say (or we used to!) that such-and-such an adjective (usually) 'is the word' or (more poetic/literary/old fashioned) remind people that 'something is our watchword'. Careful's the word when we are dealing with a mad bull! Change is the watchword for this year's party conference. Rehabilitation became the watchword of D.C.’s juvenile justice system.

@KateBunting - maybe usual partly because it adds immediacy and urgency (by discarding formality)?

@MichaelHarvey You've hit the nail on the head with "Careful's the word". "careful" is how we should be. Mum is how we should be.  It is a specialized meaning of "the word".  A word expressing a credo or policy or outlook, something to be followed or obeyed or lived up to.

The Australian Retailer sees nothing wrong with quoting whatever is 'the word', so maybe I'll withdraw my comment about 'mum' - ‘Cautious’ is the word when it comes to 5G - Australians' attitude to 5G remains cautious, despite the speeding up of consumer digital adoption and the introduction of new trends as a result of the Covid-19 lockdown.

'You've hit the nail on the head' - except when thumb's the word, eh?

Mum's the word" is  a common idiomatic expression in English, meaning "keep quiet" or "secret". It's often used to remind someone to stay silent or not reveal confidential information.
's contraction has various meanings.
“How's” is short for anything that ends in “s” such as “How is, How was, How does, How has, etc.”
This versatility of the "'s" contraction can sometimes lead to ambiguity, but context usually helps understand the intended meaning.
